# How to handle BETWEEN clause on a partition key in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, key, between, partition

My table is like below

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  A int PRIMARY KEY,
  B int,
  C int
);
```

and I need to retrieve data with values of `A` between `10` and `1122`
In SQL we can do this using BETWEEN clause.
As Cassandra doesn't support use of >, < I couldn't able to query it.
Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To have a chance to obtain a valuable feedback, you should provide the code of your current code, the one which try to solve your problem. Pleas look at [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] and [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra does not allow that query on its own since it requires reading all the data in the table and filtering out data. You need to change your data model to support your query without operations that would not scale and cannot be efficiently distributed. You can actually make this work with the `ALLOW FILTERING` flag to acknowledge that you are ignoring all wisdom and recommendations. This is more for one off debugging and specialized bulk operations and will cause issues if you use it in your application:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE A > 10 AND A < 1122 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried using ALLOW FILTERING it's working. But I want to use it in my application where there might be issues.  Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Design your tables around your queries so that everything you want is within a partition or part of a partition. Use clustering keys for ordering. Perhaps it would be better to take a step back and review Cassandra data modeling or watch a video/class on them. This is not a relational database and you shouldn't create your tables in same way as in SQL. In the same way you wouldn't if building your data model for a key value store (Cassandra does provide more than just a KV though)

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Can u please suggest me better data model in this scenario. The problem here is I don't have any other conditions to check so if I make any other key as partition key then I need to apply condition on that key. But I want to perform this range scan on entire table. Can u please suggest me how can it be handled.

Comment: Your table is too generic for anyone to help you out and come up with a better data model. Maybe if you provide more information and answer these questions: What do A, B and C mean and how are they related to each other? Why is A a partition key? How do you want your data to be displayed?